# Running multiple dependent apps each with their own docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two apps that I would like to somehow combine with docker and docker compose. The apps are:

**API**
This I have been able to get running on docker.
Consists of the following containers: Web (rails app), postgres, and redis.

**Scraping app**
This app scrapes other websites, makes sure the data is consistent, and sends it to the API. This is the app I dunno how to get running on docker.
Its a node app and would consist of the following containers: Web (sails app), mongodb, redis, the API.

My question is if its possible to write the `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml` file for the scraping app such that it is linked to the API app, which itself is linked to at least two other containers. Or do I have to manually boot the API app before booting the scraping app?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "linked to"?  Can these simply be part of the same `docker-compose.yml`? If not, why not?

Comment: Certainly you can combine the compose files into one, and use `links` or `depends_on` to declare dependency. Then you can use `docker-compose up` to run both, or use `docker-compose run api` to run only `api` and its dependencies.